During long online video presentation when I was the only one speaking the headphones did turn off
I have really odd issue, but I lack knowledge of the possible root cause. So I don't even know how to test what is the reason behind this.
This year I started teaching on video meetings. Those type of meetings was conducted on Webinar platforms. I was with someone else during those webinars and the person was talking only at the beginning. So I was the only one speaking for about an hour. At the end of the presentation, I didn't hear the co-host of the meeting.
First time I had Wireless Logitech gaming headphones. They have this turn on/off switch so I just turned it off and on and the sound was back on. I thought that it was the headphones that turned off, but it was not the case. Next time I used wired JBL headphones and wired lavamic. And got the same effect but this time I didn't have the switch so at the end of the presentation I had no sound.
TL;DR During a long presentation when I was the only one speaking the sound in my headphones turned off
Does anybody know the possible reasons for this behavior and how I should approach finding the root cause?
The only thing that came into my mind, is to use Google Meet or Jitsi for an hour with someone from my family and see if after an hour I would still have sound. But the problem is that I can't reproduce the exact same environment because it was dedicated software similar to Zoom (but I used a web version).
Note that I don't even know what software my system is using for the sound. I don't remember if there was no recent shift from PulseAudio to something else.
I have Fedora 39 XFce.
